# Drupal Role-specific Fields & Registration Forms

Tags: drupal-7, registration, field

I have set up 2 role types:

- Vendor
- Customer

I would like to create a role-specific Vendor signup at
mysite.com/vendor-register

(And for customer, to sign up at /customer-register )

I have also been reading up on Drupal 7 user permissions and roles however can't seem to see how, during the registration / profile modification stages, only certain fields are associated with certain roles?

For example, the Vendor requires diff fields to be added during registration than the customer.

These fields/data would be specific to the Vendors and the customers' profiles.

Any help much appreciated,

gvanto
drupal7 novice

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this module, it works well 
http://drupal.org/project/profile2